# Set theory: equivalence relation proof question

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that If $G$ is an equivalence relation in $A$, then $G\circ G=G$

My try
Reflexive: $(x,x)\in G \forall x\in A$
Symmetric: If $(x,y)\in G$ then $(y,x)\in A$
Transitive: If $(x,y)\in G$ and $(y,z)\in G$ then $(x,z)\in G$

I know the definition for the composite function. But how do i elaborate my proof into expressions? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What proof? You just wrote some definitions. You want to prove the equality of two sets. Prove that each is a subset of the other.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to write but i need to prove the statement at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $$G\circ G=\{\,(x,z)\mid \exists y\in A\colon (x,y), (y,z)\in G\,\}.$$
Showing $G\subseteq G\circ G$ is easy as $(x,y)\in G$ and $(y,y)\in G$ (by reflexivity) implies $(x,y)\in G\circ G$.
Showing $G\circ G\subseteq G$ is also easy: Assume $(x,z)\in G\circ G$. Then there exists $y\in A$ with $(x,y)\in G$ and $(y,z)\in G$. By transitivity, $(x,z)\in G$, as was to be whon.

Note that we did not use symmetry at all in the proof. Indeed the claim holds also for reflexive transitive relations, such as $\le$.